# how to get the Hidden Columns Control Value in PreparingCellForEdit Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

how to get the Hidden Columns Control Value in PreparingCellForEdit Silverlight Datagrid

Code as Follows:

```
Private Sub TaskDataGrid_LoadingRow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs)

    Dim row As DataGridRow = e.Row 
    Dim cellContent As FrameworkElement = TaskDataGrid.Columns(8).GetCellContent(e.Row)

    Dim cboLabValidated As ComboBox = CType(cellContent.FindName("cboLabValidated"), ComboBox)
    Dim ViewModel As New NonFirmWareNewRequestViewModel()
    If cboLabValidated IsNot Nothing Then
        cboLabValidated.ItemsSource = ViewModel.YesNoValues
    End If 
    TaskDataGrid.Columns(1).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub
```

in the above code I am hidden the column 1 in LoadingRow Event and in need to get the value of that Column in PreparingCellForEdit

Code for PreparingCellForEdit as Follows:

```
Dim fe As FrameworkElement = TaskDataGrid.Columns(5).GetCellContent(e.Row)
                    Dim fe1 As FrameworkElement = TaskDataGrid.Columns(1).GetCellContent(e.Row)

                    Dim gridCmbo As Grid = DirectCast(fe, Grid)

                    Dim gridCmbo1 As Grid = DirectCast(fe1, Grid)

                    Dim lbltaskId As Label = CType(gridCmbo1.FindName("lbltaskId"), Label)

                    Dim cboCompVerSel As ComboBox = CType(gridCmbo.FindName("cboCompVerSel"), ComboBox)

                    Dim lblCompVer As Label = CType(gridCmbo.FindName("lblCompVer"), Label)
```

I am using label control to show column 1 and I am identifying the label control object but the content becomes empty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working fine

1) While in the Loading Row Event We should not hide the Column, if you hide the column   you cannot get the value from the column let the data Load first in the LoadingRow Event.

2) Hide the column in the Selection changed event code as follows :

```
 Private Sub TaskDataGrid_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles TaskDataGrid.SelectionChanged
        TaskDataGrid.Columns(1).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed 
    End Sub
```

this event will fire after LoadingRow Datagrid event or  PreparingCellForEdit event once the Row is loaded we can hide the column and can get the value where ever you want.If you Hide in LoadingRow event without loading the Data you cannot get the value of that Control in the Datagrid template or Data Column.